# iOS kills app in Background after some time

Tags: objective-c

Do iOS kills background apps when the battery consumption goes down by certain extent. can u specify after how much consumption of battery level do iOS starts killing background apps?? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Every app in iOS goes **inactive** after 15 minutes of being active in the background, but is not being killed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such level, as killing apps in the background might depend on what other apps do. For example, if the frontmost app needs more memory, your app might get killed to reclaim some.

The ways to cooperate with the system are to declare your background jobs using the techniques described in [this programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). For example, you can use the methods described there to request time in the background to complete your tasks.